# 'No AuthDBDUserPWQuery has been specified' error log when AuthDBDUserRealmQuery is set in Apache 2.4

Tags: apache2, basic-authentication, apache2.4

I'm trying to use `mod_authn_dbd` for authentication in Apache 2.4. I set up everything according to the documentations, and I've tested it with the directive `AuthDBDUserPWQuery` and it works finely. Now, if I try to use instead the directive `AuthDBDUserRealmQuery`, and I try an access to server, the `error.log` shows

```
[authn_dbd:error] [pid 24419:tid 140371559429888] [client some_ip:some_port] AH01654: No AuthDBDUserPWQuery has been specified
```

In the following I report my `000-default.conf` file (I'm putting my stuff there as I need to Reverse Proxy).

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    DBDriver mysql
    DBDParams "host=localhost port=3306 user=my_user pass=my_pass dbname=the_db"
    DBDMin  2
    DBDKeep 4
    DBDMax  10
    DBDExptime 300

    <Location />
      AuthName "You Must Login"
      AuthType Basic
      AuthBasicProvider dbd
      AuthDBDUserRealmQuery "SELECT ENCRYPT(password) FROM password WHERE username = %s AND realm = %s"
      Require valid-user
    <Location/>

</VirtualHost>
# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Answer (score 0):

After struggling a bit, I found the answer. According to the [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_authn_dbd.html), `AuthDBDUserRealmQuery` works only with `mod_auth_digest`. It is written in the description, although is slightly hidden and misleading. The final config file should appear something like

```
    <Directory />
      AuthName "Your realm"
      AuthType Digest
      AuthDigestDomain /
      AuthDigestProvider dbd
      AuthDBDUserRealmQuery "SELECT MD5(password) FROM password WHERE username = %s AND realm = %s"
      Require valid-user
    </Directory>
```

Note the `MD5` method called in the query to match the digest applied by the browser when sending the password. That call must be done only if the password in your DB are not already 'digested'.